# Como associar uma variavel a um ID?

Tags: android, button, background, background-color

Tenho um array integer e preciso de associar esse valor a um determinado botão, para mudar o seu backgound. se no array haver o numero "40", preciso que o "botão40" mude de cor. e por ai adiante, até todo o array ser verificado. Basicamente, o que preciso é de associar uma variável a um ID.

Tipo: Button(X).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
Sendo X uma variavel INT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tem algumas opções. A que eu aconselho seria usar um simples HashMap.

```
Map<Integer, Button> buttonsHash = new HashMap<Integer, Button>();

public Button getButton(int position){
    return buttonsHash.get(position);
}

public void addButton(int position, Button button){
    buttonsHash.put(position, button);
}

public void changeButtonColor(int position, int color){
    Button button = getButton(position);
    if(button != null) button.setBackgroundColor(color);
    else throw new NullPointerException();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tendo o Id de uma View é possível obter a referência a ela utilizando o método [findViewById()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewById(int)) do layout que a contém.

Assim, se os valores que estão no array correspondem aos Ids declarados no xml, é fácil corresponder esses valores aos botões.

```
int[] arrayButtons = new int[]
    {
         R.id.Button00,
         R.id.Button01,
         R.id.Button02,
         R.id.Button03,
         R.id.Button04,
         ...
    }

int idButton04 = arrayButtons[4];
Button button04 = findViewById(idButton04);
button04.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
```